# Clear GridControl focused row after ItemsSource updated

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress, caliburn.micro

I'm working on legacy code and I stumbled upon an issue that got me stuck for a week. I would like to hear others' opinion about it.

The case includes parent - children items: when a parent node is selected, a `devexpress.xpf.Grid` bound to `BindingList<Child> children` is populated with corresponding data. Say, a row was selected/highlighted within the grid. When another parent node is selected, the `children` list is cleared, new items are added and they get displayed in the grid successfully.
Actual behavior: The previously selected row will remain selected.
Desired behavior: To clear selection when the content is updated.

**Concern 1:**
`ItemsSourceChanged` will fire once at the first loading, but not for every update . I believe it's because the items source isn't changing per se, the object reference is still the same, but the content is updated and there's no `ItemsSourceUpdated` that I could find. Also, `TargetUpdated` only fires once at the first loading too despite having `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` set to true and `Child` implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Concern 2:**
When updating the children list, the `ListChangedEvent` was suppressed to avoid firing for each added  item. `RaiseListChangedEvents` is set to false, some business logic happens, then `RaiseListChangedEvents` is set back to true followed by `ResetBindings()` to fire the event. When this suppression is removed, the selection is cleared as desired. I suppose there's something getting disabled but not enabled again?!

**Concern 3:**
For the very first load of children into the empty tableview, the first row is selected by default. This can be stopped by setting `AllowInitiallyFocusedRow` to false in XAML. while researching this issue, I found `KeepFocusedRowOnUpdate` which can be set to false to achieve the desired behavior. However, `KeepFocusedRowOnUpdate` isn't available for the GridControl being used and I couldn't find any equivalent. What struck me is that there are many threads on Devexpress support center for achieving the opposite, people want to keep/retain/preserve previous selection. that made my search even more harder.

**Concern 4:**
The VM holds `ReadOnlyCollection<Child> SelectedChildren` not explicitly bound to the view but Caliburn micro is used so a lot of naming convention is at work I suppose. I suspected the readonly was keeping the selection from being cleared but when removing the suppression as mentioned in point2 the selection gets cleared indeed. Unless it's a very specific case combination between these two?!

Any ideas, pointers, or similar experiences are appreciated.
PS: There's a lot of code involved so I didn't know which would be useful to add here. If there's anything specific you think would be helpful to add, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, for devexpress components, documentation must be read carefully. In any way, you can check first  SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedGridItems}" SelectionMode="Row" on GridControl

Comment: Focused and selected items are generally misunderstood. If they are bound somehow, it might create some GUI problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case some source code would be useful. In any case to debug focusing problem on GridControl, you shoud check following properties:

On `GridControl`

```
  ItemsSource="{Binding GridItemSource}"
  SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedGridItems}"
  SelectionMode="Row"
```

On `TableView`

```
FocusedRow="{Binding FocusedRow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Check if they are somehow bound together or not. Check also if there are some DXEvent bindings on VM like `SelectionChanged`.

Comment: I just explicitly added a binding for the selected items and changed the eadonly to observable collection in VM for this to work. and the TableView FocusedRow is obsolete but I didn't need to use it anyway.